# Changing a Switchery checkbox state from code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, checkbox

How do I programatically change a [jQuery Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) checkbox state from checked to unchecked (and vice versa)?

I tried using `global_switch_sound.prop('checked', true)` on the checkbox element but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```html
<input id="sound-active-input" type="checkbox"  />
```

JavaScript:

```js
 global_switch_sound = new Switchery(document.querySelector('#sound-active-input'));
```

Comment: You have the code for us?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.switchery').click();
```

It should trigger a click and switch.
OR this:

```
$('.switchery').trigger('click');
```

Comment: This changes the state of the checkbox of the rendered one, but when I run the function global_switch_sound.markedAsSwitched() it returns "true" always, no matter what the state of the checkbox is.

Comment: OK, this one should be fine, because I ran the 'isChecked()' function for the element and it shows the correct state. Do you know if there is a native function to change the state, rather using this workaround ?

Comment: you mean if there is a funtion in Switchery?

Comment: I never used the plugin but  i couldn't find anything on the plugin page

Comment: The click trigger doesn't work for some reason, I think it might due to the plugin duplicating the ID to the new span element of the switch.. checking it out..

Comment: Your sure that it is triggered on the switch element?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48046/discussion-between-idan-shechter-and-rickdep)

Comment: doesn't work for disabled switches. needed a more generic solution.

Comment: Thanks mate.  This helped. You have to add 2 attributes like this to input element
<input type="checkbox" data-plugin="switchery" data-color="#1bb99a" />

then use the above code in the script section... ofc there should be an API call that happens when the click is triggered.

Answer (score 32):

If anyone is like me and wanted a solution that goes beyond ".click()"ing the DOM.  The following function takes the Switchery object and a boolean to indicate whether the switch should be checked or unchecked(true/ false respectively):

```
function setSwitchery(switchElement, checkedBool) {
    if((checkedBool && !switchElement.isChecked()) || (!checkedBool && switchElement.isChecked())) {
        switchElement.setPosition(true);
        switchElement.handleOnchange(true);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var mySwitch = new Switchery($('#mySwitchCheck')[0], {
            size:"small",
            color: '#0D74E9'
        });
//Checks the switch
setSwitchery(mySwitch, true);
//Unchecks the switch
setSwitchery(mySwitch, false);
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: I used that condition together with [Aamir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22524862/6225838) (using an array of switchery objects assigned on page load). With this I avoided recreating `new Switchery` objects.

Comment: It's better than the accepted answer, because it also works for disabled switcheries.

Comment: The "if" condition could be changed to:

`if(checkedBool !== switchElement.isChecked()) { ... }`

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
function changeSwitchery(element, checked) {
  if ( ( element.is(':checked') && checked == false ) || ( !element.is(':checked') && checked == true ) ) {
    element.parent().find('.switchery').trigger('click');
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var element = $('#sound-active-input');
changeSwitchery(element, false);
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most flexible answer. You could make it even simpler by doing `element.click()`. Thanks!

Comment: it was amazing ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can simplify this:

```
// Uncheck: first set checked property to 'true', then uncheck to force UI update
$(".switchery").prop('checked', false).trigger("click");

// Check
$(".switchery").prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 7):

First you have to store all the switches in an array during initialization

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    switchery[html.getAttribute('id')] = new Switchery(html);
});
```

and create a local function to toggle switch like this

```
toggleSwitchery(id)
{
    var s = switchery[id];
    s.setPosition(true);
    s.handleOnchange(true);
}
```

this worked for me. 
In case you face any UI issue i.e. switch moves some extra pixels then open switchery.js and replace jack.offsetWidth  by  30 in *Switchery.prototype.setPosition* function

Comment: Thanks...i was searching this from last two days

Answer (score 4):

```
function toggleSwitch(switch_elem, on) {
    if (on){ // turn it on
        if ($(switch_elem)[0].checked){ // it already is so do 
            // nothing
        }else{
            $(switch_elem).trigger('click').attr("checked", "checked"); // it was off, turn it on
        }
    }else{ // turn it off
        if ($(switch_elem)[0].checked){ // it's already on so 
            $(switch_elem).trigger('click').removeAttr("checked"); // turn it off
        }else{ // otherwise 
            // nothing, already off
        }
    }
}
```

call by using

```
toggleSwitch("#switch_element", true);
toggleSwitch("#switch_element", false);
```

Needs error checking and stuff but works well, requires jQuery and tested on Switchery 0.8.1 which came packaged with a prebuilt theme I've been using (Altair Admin)

Answer (score 4):

When you need to check/uncheck all switchery checkboxes the solution with JQuery is:

```
$( '.js-switches' ).each( function() {
// for checking
    if ( !this.checked ) $( this ).trigger( 'click' );
// for unchecking
    if ( this.checked ) $( this ).trigger( 'click' );
} );
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simple set like this with your checkbox id,

```
$('#sound-active-input').prop('checked', true);
```

#### DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/VHZY8/2/

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work dynamically for me when I run it in the console to change to state

Comment: it does not work because you change state before initializing plugin. Question is, how to change state after init of it.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function changeSwitch(switch_id,active) {
    var check = document.querySelector(switch_id);
    //console.log("check",switch_id,check.checked,"to",active);
    if ( !check.checked && active ){
        var c = $(check).next('span').attr("class").replace("switchery ","");
        var l = {"switchery-large":"26px","switchery-small":"13px","switchery-default":"20px"}; 
        $(check).prop("checked",true).next('span').attr("style","box-shadow: rgb(38, 185, 154) 0px 0px 0px 16px inset; border-color: rgb(38, 185, 154); background-color: rgb(38, 185, 154); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s, background-color 1.2s;").find('small').attr("style","left: "+l[c]+"; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);");
    }else if ( check.checked && !active ){
        $(check).prop("checked",false).next('span').attr("style","box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;").find('small').attr("style","left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;");
    }
}

changeSwitch(".js-switch",true);
```

If you try this to reset form, use it before:

```
changeSwitch(".js-switch",true);
$("#frm_id").trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 2):

Combined a few answers, works with v0.8.2.

```
    function setSwitchery(switchElement, checkedBool) {
        if (checkedBool && !switchElement.checked) { // switch on if not on
            $(switchElement).trigger('click').attr("checked", "checked");
        } else if (!checkedBool && switchElement.checked) { // switch off if not off
            $(switchElement).trigger('click').removeAttr("checked");
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
var switchElement = $('#mySwitchInput');
setSwitchery(switchElement, false);
```

Comment: (!switchElement.checked) not working well. In my situation i solved it with (!switchElement.is(':checked'))

Answer (score 1):

If the `$('#sound-active-input').click()` did not work you, you can try triggering a click on the span that switchery creates after the checkbox.

```
$('#sound-active-input').next('span').click();
```

That was the only way it worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from native github issue tracker link. Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3am89/

This is the piece of code you need to add in and manually call this function to re-render the button:

```
function onChange(el) {
    if (typeof Event === 'function' || !document.fireEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        event.initEvent('change', true, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        el.fireEvent('onchange');
    }
}
```

The issue that describes this scenoario is 
https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the switches with Bootstrap collapse, programmatically setting the state fails to expand the data-target every second time. Timing issues with the click handler I assume. This makes it work

```
     function setSwitchery(switchElement, checkedBool) {

        if (checkedBool && !switchElement.checked) { // switch on if not on
            $(switchElement).trigger('click').prop("checked", false);
            // make sure the data target shows
            $($(switchElement).data('target')).addClass('show');
        } else if (!checkedBool && switchElement.checked) { // switch off if not off
            $(switchElement).trigger('click').prop("checked", false);
            $($(switchElement).data('target')).removeClass('show');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer: because I don't want to trigger the change event that will execute a defined function

```
var myCheckbox = $("id_your_checkbox")

// your new value true or false
myCheckbox.checked = true;

//remove the old switchery
$('#' + myCheckbox.id).siblings("span.switchery").remove();

//and recreate the switchery
new Switchery(document.querySelector('#' + myCheckbox.getAttribute('id') + ''), {
    color: '#1abc9c',
    jackColor: '#fff'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('selector').click(function () {
        $("selector").toggle(this.checked);
    });


if you are using jquery version <1.6

use this 
$('#checkMeOut').attr('checked');
```

Comment: doesn't work, just shows a black border around the original checkbox which is hidden in the code to show the rendered one

Comment: This doesn't change the state (visually) of the rendered checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found a solution to this problem, as I too had the same problem and after reading through your discussion with @Rickdep, though he was not able to help you (even though the solution he posted has a check next to it), you guys did point me in the right direction and I was able to come up with a solution, so thank you. Anyway, here is the solution I came up with.

First, you need to be using the class set on the span element you're generating with switchery.js, on your $('.class').click(); function: so for example, the span being generating in my solution looks as such:

```
<span class="switcher-questionnaire" style="border-color: rgb(121, 186, 97); box-shadow: rgb(121, 186, 97) 0px 0px 0px 16px inset; transition: border 0.7s, box-shadow 0.7s, background-color 2.0999999999999996s; -webkit-transition: border 0.7s, box-shadow 0.7s, background-color 2.0999999999999996s; background-color: rgb(121, 186, 97);">

<small style="left: 50px; transition: left 0.35s; -webkit-transition: left 0.35s;"></small>

</span>
```

Since the class I am telling switchery.js to generate in this solution is "switcher-questionnaire", that is the class I want to use in my click function, which looks like this:

```
$('.switcher-questionnaire').click( function() {
        if ($(this).children('small').css("left") === '50px') {
            $('.questionnaire-overlay').show();
        } else {
            $('.questionnaire-overlay').hide();
        }
        console.log('Clicked');
});
```

For my solution, I wanted to be able to use the switch to hide and show an overlay layer that disables access to specified content the user is viewing if the user determines the section 'does not apply'. Since switchery.js hides the checkbox and replaces that checkbox with a span that creates the Apple-esque switch we all want, but since switchery.js does not actually change the checked/unchecked state of the hidden checkbox, you are unable to use a boolean statement that is actively validating against the checkbox 'checked' attribute. This being the case, I most significant change I noticed the switch does when being toggled is changing the left position of the 'small' element from 50px to 0px when it is clicked:

```
<small style="left: 50px; transition: left 0.35s; -webkit-transition: left 0.35s;"></small>
```

I chose this as what I would use as a boolean solution to check against with a little bit of jQuery's magical sauce.

I am pretty much a noob when it comes to programming, but I felt it would be helpful if I explained some of my thought process when solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the AngularJS version, the uiSwitch directive is incomplete to support this.
You must to add a $formatter for the ngModel in the uiSwitch directive that update the switcher value.

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {

    $timeout(function() {

        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
        switcher.setPosition(value);

    });

});
```

With this, when you update the model in your code will be reflected in the ui-switch directive.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c0wojsfy/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Checkit!

```
function changeSwitch(sltor,active) {
    var check = $(sltor).get(0);
    if ( (!check.checked && active) || (check.checked && !active) ){
        $(check).next('span').trigger('click')
    }
}
changeSwitch('.onlyOnThisDate',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    let switchery = new Switchery(html, {
        size: 'medium',
        secondaryColor: '#DC3545'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input-switchery radio-checkbox" id="chkId">
```

Javascript

```
 new Switchery("#chkId");
 chkId.element.checked = true; //true or false
 chkId.handleOnchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works for me with several switchery checkboxes.

Notice important, to set the switchery to false, you set the prop to checked(true), the generated "click" event will switch it to false and update the switchery.

```
$('#canBePublished').prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
if canBePublished == 1) {
     $('#canBePublished').prop('checked', false).trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My method does not click on the checkbox, so it does not trigger unnecessary events:

```
$('#switch').prop('checked', true/false).siblings().remove();
new Switchery($('#switch')[0]);
```